# Allow Logged In Wordpress users to read a folder of HTML pages

Tags: html, wordpress, directory

I have a WordPress site installed in the root folder. Beneath the root is a /docs folder with a bunch of older HTML files. I'd like to allow only logged in WordPress users to be able to have access to those /docs HTML pages (not to be confused with WordPress 'pages').

I created a WordPress 'portal' page which displays links to the /docs pages if the visitor is logged in. I would also like to put in a textual search function (which I know how to do) so logged in visitors can get a list of relevant /docs HTML pages

What I -don't- know how to do is prevent -not- logged in visitors from direct access to the /docs pages for both links and searches?

I know I could do these if I converted the HTML pages to PHP and checked an referrer. But I don't want to have to redo all the old HTML if possible (if I have to do -that- I'll just import them into a WordPress taxonomy---but I hope to avoid that!)

I looked at .htaccess and I was hoping to perhaps set an ENV variable or use REFERRER, but I keep reading that such things are not reliable.

Ideas?

Comment: I don't know what the policy is regarding WP questions on SO, but if you haven't tried already you might want to post this question over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks... wasn't aware there was a problem with WP questions here. Will re-post over -there-...

Comment: There may be no problem at all - I just thought it would be worth asking at wordpress.stackexchange.com since you'll find a lot of WP experts there!